# Blue Air API SOAP Call (navitaire)

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I am facing a problem, I am not new to PHP but I am a very beginner on Web Services, XML etc. I am called to implement an Flights Api which will retrieve only available flights. Blue air told me that i have to do the two following steps:

1) Logon using the the Logon function in https://0bapi.navitaire.com/SessionManager.svc and send the following request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
<LogonRequest xmlns="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices/ServiceContracts/SessionService">
<logonRequestData xmlns:a="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices/DataContracts/Session" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<a:DomainCode>EXT</a:DomainCode> 
<a:AgentName>MYUSERNAME</a:AgentName> 
<a:Password>MYPASSWORD</a:Password> 
<a:LocationCode>EXT</a:LocationCode> 
<a:RoleCode i:nil="true" /> 
<a:TerminalInfo i:nil="true" /> 
</logonRequestData>
</LogonRequest>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

So far so good, i have done the following:

```
$request = '<LogonRequest xmlns="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices/ServiceContracts/SessionService">
<logonRequestData xmlns:a="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices/DataContracts/Session" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <a:DomainCode>EXT</a:DomainCode> 
  <a:AgentName>MYUSERNAME</a:AgentName> 
  <a:Password>MYPASSWORD</a:Password> 
  <a:LocationCode>EXT</a:LocationCode> 
  <a:RoleCode i:nil="true" /> 
  <a:TerminalInfo i:nil="true" /> 
  </logonRequestData>
  </LogonRequest>
  ';
```

and have Successfully retrieved the Signature key which will be needed later on.

2) Use the GetAvailability function in https://0bapi.navitaire.com/BookingManager.svc in order to get the results. The sample Request they sent me is:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
  <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:Signature xmlns:h="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices">TjPD2smLRzw=|lh90Ck0rsuAntqj8NdZk0IorrNHHgZegW2sQV3WSq3fhH4/UGkUJZh7WlhvClvceOZNcklqvC9lY7UUnhDOzPJFyZBwu8/ULevcprBFGgP/rfJsDZlwG/m2e3PKcNAZ4zVJXdvUgb/4=</h:Signature> 
    </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
  <GetAvailabilityRequest xmlns="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices/ServiceContracts/BookingService">
  <TripAvailabilityRequest xmlns="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices/DataContracts/Booking" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <AvailabilityRequests>
  <AvailabilityRequest>
    <DepartureStation>OTP</DepartureStation> 
    <ArrivalStation>LCA</ArrivalStation> 
    <BeginDate>2015-03-10T00:00:00</BeginDate> 
    <EndDate>2015-03-15T00:00:00</EndDate> 
    <CarrierCode i:nil="true" /> 
    <FlightNumber i:nil="true" /> 
    <FlightType>All</FlightType> 
    <PaxCount>1</PaxCount> 
    <Dow>Daily</Dow> 
    <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode> 
    <DisplayCurrencyCode i:nil="true" /> 
    <DiscountCode i:nil="true" /> 
    <PromotionCode i:nil="true" /> 
    <AvailabilityType>Default</AvailabilityType> 
    <SourceOrganization i:nil="true" /> 
    <MaximumConnectingFlights>0</MaximumConnectingFlights> 
    <AvailabilityFilter>Default</AvailabilityFilter> 
    <FareClassControl>LowestFareClass</FareClassControl> 
    <MinimumFarePrice>0</MinimumFarePrice> 
    <MaximumFarePrice>0</MaximumFarePrice> 
    <ProductClassCode i:nil="true" /> 
    <SSRCollectionsMode>All</SSRCollectionsMode> 
    <InboundOutbound>Both</InboundOutbound> 
    <NightsStay>0</NightsStay> 
    <IncludeAllotments>false</IncludeAllotments> 
    <BeginTime i:nil="true" /> 
    <EndTime i:nil="true" /> 
    <DepartureStations i:nil="true" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" /> 
    <ArrivalStations i:nil="true" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" /> 
    <FareTypes i:nil="true" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" /> 
    <ProductClasses i:nil="true" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" /> 
    <FareClasses i:nil="true" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" /> 
  <PaxPriceTypes>
  <PaxPriceType>
    <PaxType>ADT</PaxType> 
    <PaxDiscountCode i:nil="true" /> 
    </PaxPriceType>
    </PaxPriceTypes>
    <JourneySortKeys i:nil="true" xmlns:a="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices/DataContracts/Common/Enumerations" /> 
    <TravelClassCodes i:nil="true" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" /> 
    </AvailabilityRequest>
    </AvailabilityRequests>
    </TripAvailabilityRequest>
    </GetAvailabilityRequest>
    </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```

My code for this is:

```
$request2='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>'
    . '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> '
    . '<s:Header>  '
    . '<h:Signature xmlns:h="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices">'
    .$result['Signature']
    .'</h:Signature> '
    . '  </s:Header>'
    . ' <s:Body>'
    . '<GetAvailabilityRequest xmlns="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices/ServiceContracts/BookingService"> '
    . '<TripAvailabilityRequest xmlns="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices/DataContracts/Booking" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">'
    . ' <AvailabilityRequests> '
    . '<AvailabilityRequest> '
    . ' <DepartureStation>OTP</DepartureStation> '
    . '  <ArrivalStation>LCA</ArrivalStation>  '
    . ' <BeginDate>2015-03-10T00:00:00</BeginDate>'
    . '   <EndDate>2015-03-15T00:00:00</EndDate>  '
    . ' <CarrierCode i:nil="true" />  '
    . ' <FlightNumber i:nil="true" /> '
    . '  <FlightType>All</FlightType>  '
    . ' <PaxCount>1</PaxCount>   '
    . '<Dow>Daily</Dow> '
    . '  <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>'
    . '   <DisplayCurrencyCode i:nil="true" /> '
    . '  <DiscountCode i:nil="true" />  '
    . ' <PromotionCode i:nil="true" />  '
    . ' <AvailabilityType>Default</AvailabilityType>  '
    . ' <SourceOrganization i:nil="true" /> '
    . '  <MaximumConnectingFlights>0</MaximumConnectingFlights>  '
    . ' <AvailabilityFilter>Default</AvailabilityFilter> '
    . '  <FareClassControl>LowestFareClass</FareClassControl> '
    . '  <MinimumFarePrice>0</MinimumFarePrice>  '
    . ' <MaximumFarePrice>0</MaximumFarePrice> '
    . '  <ProductClassCode i:nil="true" />  '
    . ' <SSRCollectionsMode>All</SSRCollectionsMode>  '
    . ' <InboundOutbound>Both</InboundOutbound> '
    . '  <NightsStay>0</NightsStay> '
    . '  <IncludeAllotments>false</IncludeAllotments>  '
    . ' <BeginTime i:nil="true" /> '
    . '  <EndTime i:nil="true" />   '
    . '<DepartureStations i:nil="true" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" />  '
    . ' <ArrivalStations i:nil="true" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" />  '
    . ' <FareTypes i:nil="true" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" /> '
    . '  <ProductClasses i:nil="true" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" />  '
    . ' <FareClasses i:nil="true" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" /> '
    . ' <PaxPriceTypes> '
    . '<PaxPriceType>  '
    . '<PaxType>ADT</PaxType>   '
    . '<PaxDiscountCode i:nil="true" /> '
    . '  </PaxPriceType>  '
    . '</PaxPriceTypes> '
    . ' <JourneySortKeys i:nil="true" xmlns:a="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices/DataContracts/Common/Enumerations" />   '
    . '<TravelClassCodes i:nil="true" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" />  '
    . ' </AvailabilityRequest>  '
    . '</AvailabilityRequests>'
    . '  </TripAvailabilityRequest> '
    . ' </GetAvailabilityRequest>   '
    . ' </s:Body>  '
    . '</s:Envelope>';



$client2 = new SoapClient('https://0bapi.navitaire.com/BookingManager.svc?WSDL');

$result33 = $client2->GetAvailability($request2);
```

I only get this result:

```
  Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:InternalServiceFault] Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Does anyone has an idea?

Thank you in advance! (also, if someone could format the question properly i would be very thankful as i think i am to stupid to figure out how this actually works...)

Comment: I forgot to add the first actual call 
$client->setEndpoint("https://0bapi.navitaire.com/SessionManager.svc");
$client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';



$result = $client->call("Logon", $request, 'https://0bapi.navitaire.com/SessionManager.svc', 'LogonRequest',NULL,NULL,'document','literal');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a function with the SoapClient in PHP you need to pass a PHP object with the parameters in it, not the XML. The SoapClient does all the XML writing and reading for you which makes things nice and easy.

Hence -  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Refer to the WSDL to see the structure and datatypes for your object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you please be more specific about the "refer to the WSDL"? I do not know what you mean.. (sorry very little knowledge on wsdl)

Comment: if you open "https://0bapi.navitaire.com/BookingManager.svc?WSDL" in a web browser it will give you the spec for the web service, all the functions and datatypes within it. The SoapClient reads the WSDL and works out how to talk to the SOAP interface so you need to provide SoapClient with the parameters the function needs as PHP objects, the SoapClient will convert those to XML to talk to the SOAP interface. It will convert rhe response XML to PHP objects too.

Comment: I can't open the WSDL here so I guess it's protected in some way.

Comment: Yes, it is IP based and they have only my servers IP in their firewall. i opened it in a web browser and i got something that will not help i guess.. http://prntscr.com/6d024k any suggestions?

Comment: I did a mistake before but i got the whole wsdl. its located here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/44222387/soap.xml

As far as i understand the problem would be the Request Headers? Am i somewhere close?

Answer (score 0):

While this is an old question, I ran into the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error this week with another Navitaire airline. I thought I would share my solution, as it is unrelated to the solution offered, and also not very obvious (took me hours!).

You will notice in the code provided in the question that all of the elements in the XML start with a capital letter, except for logonRequestData which has a lowercase l. Some of the requests have this lowercase letter, while most of the requests available from the Navitaire system have a capital. Getting the wrong case was, for me at least, causing the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error to be returned by the API.